# Creating MERGED file from ditamap and then filtering it

Tags: ant, build.xml, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I'm a newbie in DITA OT and I am trying to get just the merged file from my ditamap and after upply xsl to it, but I dont need any other output.

I was thinking that I could use some part of the dita-ot source code that is doing merging or to make sort of "cutted" plugin that produces just the merged xml file and proccess xsl for it, and then gives the filtered xml file.

As I understood, there is a build.xml that is making this job using dost.jar, but I cannot configure, what exactly do I need to use from it.  Or is it possible to create just merged file seperately, not starting the transformation, so I can use it for my later needs?

I am very appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a special DITA OT plugin which can be integrated in the DITA OT and used to create just the merged document:

https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-merged/tree/master/com.oxygenxml.merged

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to publish to PDF and you set the parameter clean.temp to no, after the transformation is over you should obtain in the transformation temporary files directory a file called mapFileName_MERGED.xml which has all topic references expanded.

Comment: thank you for the answer, yes, I have found that, but I dont need the actual pdf file as an output. Maybe I have defined my question wrong, but what I am aiming for, is just to get the merged file from the ditamap and then apply xsl code to it. I was just thinking that I could use some part of the dita-ot source code for implementing my task.Or to make sort of "cutted" plugin that produces just the merged xml file and proccess xsl for it, but nothing else.